# Chrome browser AJAX issue with async: false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajax.beginform

If I am running same code in Mozilla (aprt from Chrome browser) its working fine but in Google Chrome its not working because of `async: false`

If I am making `async: true` then its working but need to reload the page.So how to handle this in Chrome browser

```
var submitpage = function () {
    var loading_dev = 'body';
    run_waitMe(loading_dev);
    $.ajax({
        url: window.updatetestUrl + "?v=" + Math.random(),
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            //run_waitMe_close(loading_dev);
        },
        error: function () {
            // run_waitMe_close(loading_dev);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What is the problem you get?

Comment: have you tried debugging code using `debugger;`?? and what `run_waitMe()` doing?

Comment: `its not working` is not enough for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: @Don'tPanic its not working means in this process i am redirect to home page,and in this  response( url: window.updatetestUrl + "?v=" + Math.random(),) which is coming from this ajax request.the update value is not getting.but if we reload the page then update value is coming from ajax

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to make your request non-asyncronous? AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** JSON and XML HTTP requests. As an async request, your call is going to be sent off without caring about its effect or result. The call will be sent out and then the line of code under it will be executed without caring about your call's response.

If you want your code to do something *after your request is finished*, you need to define it in your success function (and maybe uncomment run_waitMe_close).

```
success: function (response) {
            run_waitMe_close(loading_dev);
            //Do other desired work here
},
```